# Adobe error after first flv video

Tags: php, javascript, html, adobe, flv

I'm using php, javascript, and html/css to display flv files on a tooltip. It works fine however after the first flv, the others appear to have the "This content requires the Adobe Flash Player." message.

The PHP:

```
$tooltip .= "
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
        var playervars = {
            contentpath: '',
            video: \"$url\",
            preview: \"demo-preview.jpg\",
            skin: \"skin-applestyle.swf\",
            skincolor: \"0x2c8cbd\"
            // ...
            //see documentation for all the parameters
        };
        var params = { scale: \"scale\", allowfullscreen: \"true\", salign: \"tl\", bgcolor: \"#ffffff\", play: \"true\" };
        var attributes = { align: \"left\", base: \".\" };

        swfobject.embedSWF(\"../media/flvplayer/flvplayer.swf\", \"videoCanvas\", \"256\", \"210\", \"9.0.28\", \"../flvplayer/expressInstall.swf\", playervars, params, attributes);
    </script>

    <div id=\"videoCanvas\" style=\"margin:0px;visbility:visible;\">
        <p>This content requires the Adobe Flash Player.</p>
        <p><a href=\"http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer\"><img src=\"http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif\" alt=\"Get Adobe Flash player\" /></a>
        </p>
    </div>
";
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="thetooltip"><img src="/images/icon.png" alt="questions" width="12" height="12" border="0" />
    <span>
        <?php echo $tooltip; ?>
    </span>
</div>
```

I am using the method of pure css for tooltips, the span is the video showing on a tooltip.

As I said the first tooltip pops up and plays the video perfectly, every flv after that displays the adobe error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still having this issue? Here's what I found.

According to some of the documentation here http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation , in this line:

```
swfobject.embedSWF(\"../media/flvplayer/flvplayer.swf\", \"videoCanvas\", \"256\", \"210\", \"9.0.28\", \"../flvplayer/expressInstall.swf\", playervars, params, attributes);
```

The `\"videoCanvas\"` part refers to the ID of the object you want to replace with the video. When you do the first tooltip, the  `<div id=\"videoCanvas\"` is created on the page. But, I suspect that perhaps it's not being destroyed when the tooltip goes away. So that when the next one tries to load, there is now more than one div with the `id=videoCanvas` in the document. The ID's need to be unique, or the div needs to be completely removed from the document after the tooltip closes.